# Excel charting data

Tags: excel, charts

I'm having a hell of a time doing this...I want the vertical axis to represent how many times an ID appears and the horizontal to be the ID. So in essence the bar represents how often that ID appears in the column.

Any tips?

EDIT: for clarity...I have Column A loaded with IDs - might be 100 or more. I want a bar chart to show me how many times the ID has appeared. Just like below but with a bar going up to the # of times it appeared. I thought this was simple but charts don't seem to work this way. The IDs are going to be different so I don't think countif will work for this as that only works if you have a certain string.

```
     Column A
     ID1
     ID2
     ID4
     ID3
     ID1
     ID4
     ID8
     ID4
     ID5
     ID6
     ID7
     ID1
     ID8
     ID8
     ID1
     ID9
     ID8
     ID10



10  |
 9  |
 8  |
 7  |
 6  |
 5  |
 4  |
 3  |
 2  |
 1  |______________________________________________________________
      ID1   ID2  ID3  ID4  ID5  ID6  ID7  ID8  ID9  ID10
```

Comment: You haven't provided much information. For example, do you have a list of IDs or do you need to extract the IDs from the column? In any event, there should be an easy enough solution involving `CountIf`

Comment: There is a list of ID'S in a column. I want the chart to show how many times the ID appeared in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PivotChart will do this quickly. To create one do the following:

- Add a header to the column for the PivotTable to use
- Put the cursor somewhere in your range of data
- Go to "Insert" in the ribbon
- Select PivotTable
- Click OK
- Add the field to both Rows and Values
- Select the "Analyze" tab in the ribbon
- Select PivotChart
- Click OK

If the values are showing "Sum of" instead of "Count of", then do the following:

- Double click on the header "Sum of [field]"
- Change the selection to Count
- Click OK

Comment: DING DING DING....we have a winner. Thank you so much. Just have to make a pivot table, then chart it.

Comment: If you do this on a regular basis, you can look at writing VBA to make it into a single button click to generate everything.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution: In the following image, I first put the distinct ID's in Column B, then in C1 I entered `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$18,B1)`, copied it down, then selected columns B, C and inserted a column chart:

[image]

The various chart elements can be clicked on and e.g. column width adjusted.

Comment: This does seem like a good solution - however, getting the distinct IDs would be a pain if there are 100+, which my end result may just have.

Comment: copy column A to column B. Under `Data` first sort the ID's then invoke `Remove Duplicates`.